Run command after reattaching to GNU Screen
I use GNU Screen to run programs. One of my programs sets up a custom cursor colour. When I reattach to the program via GNU Screen, the cursor does not restore to the custom colour, until I refresh the screen in the program.
I'd like to config GNU Screen to always run a refresh command after I reattach. Is this possible?
